# kXML and LWUIT to build an RSS Reader

Tags: java-me, rss, lwuit, kxml

New here. I'm currently doing an RSS Reader for J2ME for a device called Samsung Corby. Here is my question.

Is there anyone who are doing RSS Readers with kXML and LWUIT before? I got the basic idea for kXML, but for LWUIT to work with kXML, there's no sample code or sample app that I can refer to.

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few people are using kXML with LWUIT but since these are completely separate technologies there isn't much discussion on the matter.

For RSS though, check out LWUIT4IO which has RSS reading API's including an RSS reader component.

Comment: I see. I've ditched that. Doing full time Android programming.